# How do I create an unspecified file path

Tags: c#, winforms, file-io

I need to copy file.pdf to the AppData folder in my Winforms app but since this will be used by many people I need to have a generic path that finds

```
iFile.CopyTo("somethinghere...//AppData//Temp//file.pdf");
```

and copy the said file.

Comment: Do you mean you want the one file to be in one place which is accessible to all users, or that each user should get his own copy of the file in his own AppData directory?

Comment: @RichieHindle Other users will use this .exe locally

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)` will get the appdata folder for the current user.

If you want a single copy of your PDF for all users, use `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData)` instead.

[MSDN on Environment.GetFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getfolderpath.aspx)
[MSDN on Environment.SpecialFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx)

Comment: yup SpecialFolder.ApplicationData did the trick, my gratitude!

Comment: You should be aware that ordinary users don't have write permission to CommonApplicationData.  Your installer might need to create a world-writable file or directory there.